# Generating a 3D CAPTCHA [pic]

Tags: python, graphics, captcha

I would like to write a Python script that would generate a 3D [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) like this one:
[image: teabag captcha]

Which graphics libraries can I use?

Source: [ocr-research.org.ua](http://ocr-research.org.ua/teabag.html)

Comment: Just another question: is 3d captcha harder to ocr?

Comment: Much much harder. Read the 'source' for more info.

Comment: Oh no, did someone really call it teabag??

Comment: Yes. And they actually sell this to big companies.

Answer (score 33):

There are many approaches.  I would personally create the image in Python Imaging Library using [ImageDraw](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imagedraw.htm)'s draw.text, convert to a [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) array (usint NumPy's [asarray](http://effbot.org/zone/pil-changes-116.htm)) then render with [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/mplot3d/wire3d_demo.html). (Requires Matplotlib [maintenance package](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706&package_id=82474&release_id=608756)).

Full code (in 2.5):

```
import numpy, pylab
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import matplotlib.axes3d as axes3d

sz = (50,30)

img = Image.new('L', sz, 255)
drw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 20)

drw.text((5,3), 'text', font=font)
img.save('c:/test.png')

X , Y = numpy.meshgrid(range(sz[0]),range(sz[1]))
Z = 1-numpy.asarray(img)/255

fig = pylab.figure()
ax = axes3d.Axes3D(fig)
ax.plot_wireframe(X, -Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1)
ax.set_zlim((0,50))
fig.savefig('c:/test2.png')
```

[image]

Obviously there's a little work to be done, eliminating axes, changing view angle, etc..

Comment: Very very nice. Exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot! ( I got logged out, so I cant vote you for the answer :( ).

Comment: Depends on where it is seen on my browser screen, the gray gridlines on the image disappears.

Answer (score 4):

Another binding to consider for rendering with opengl is [pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/).  Its best feature is that it is just one download.  I think it contains everything you need to implement what Anurag spells out.

I will caution you that what you're trying to do is not exactly a simple first project in 3d graphics.  If this is your first exposure to OpenGL, consider a series of tutorials like [NeHe Tutorials](http://nehe.gamedev.net/lesson.asp?index=01)  and other help from the [OpenGL website](http://wwww.opengl.org/).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I would bother with a full 3D library for what you have above. Just generate a matrix of 3D points, generate the text with something like PIL, scan over it to find which points on the grid are raised, pick a random camera angle and then project the points into a 2D image and draw them with PIL to the final image.

That being said... you may be able to use [VPython](http://vpython.org) if you don't want to do the 3D math yourself.

Comment: How do I "generate a matrix of 3d ponts"?

Comment: That would just be a list of tuples - each tuple would have 3 numbers - representing x, y and z.

Comment: RobertW: Without any prior knowledge of 3D graphics at all this calls for quite a bit of readnig before you can try that one, I think.

Comment: yes , I would say you will need to implement whole matrix manipulations or vector rotations

Comment: I dont have knowledge of 3D graphics, but I do have much linear algebra knowledge.

Comment: It is true that it would require some basic knowledge of 3D to make this work, but I'm not sure that's a bad thing. These things will need to be generated on the fly, so the simpler the better.

I just did a little bit of searching and found pyeuclid, a vector library for python that would do the job nicely.

http://code.google.com/p/pyeuclid

Essentially you would create a list of Vector3 points, and then create a Matrix4, apply some random rotations to it, and then multiply the vectors by the matrix. Then you handle the projection.

Comment: For the projection bit, the wikipedia article on 3D projection gives you the basic equations you need. After that it's just a matter of applying them and fiddling with the angles of everything to make sure the CAPTCHA is always (human) readable.

Comment: Yeah - If you have knowledge of linear algebra, then this shouldn't be terribly hard for you (and in fact, should be quite fun!). When I first learned linear I immediately started coding up basic 3D stuff. It's very cool to be able to apply more advanced math to problems you WANT to solve!

Answer (score 1):

Use Python bindings for OpenGL, http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/.

Create a 2D image of white color text over a black surface using [PIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Imaging_Library).
Make a 3D grid from this, increase z of point where color is white,
maybe set z=color value, so by blurring the image you can get real curves in the z direction.

Create an OpenGL triangle from these points, use wireframe mode while rendering.

Grab the OpenGL buffer into an image, for example,
http://python-opengl-examples.blogspot.com/2009/04/render-to-texture.html.

Comment: I would love to do this myself, given sufficient motivation ;)