# Creating 3D Captchas

Tags: python, captcha

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating a 3D CAPTCHA [pic]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021721/generating-a-3d-captcha-pic)

Can anyone suggest some free C++/Python library I can leverage to create 3D captchas?

Perhaps something along the lines of

[image]
<sub>(source: [fontforge.org](http://fontforge.org/fontforge-banner-420.jpeg))</sub>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021721/generating-a-3d-captcha-pic